# Samsung Galaxy Tab 1 layout problems

Tags: layout, tabs, resize, galaxy

I'm having trouble running my app on the Galaxy tab original 7". It appears to make everything 1.5 times bigger, i.e. if I specify 40dip for a textSize in my layout, it will display as 60 dip when I run it on the tablet.

I tried messing around with the display metrics and changing the density and densityDpi to 1. (When I run a toString of the display metrics in the Galaxy tab 2, they are both 1, whereas the Galaxy tab 1 has values of 1.5)

The app runs very well on every phone I've tested it on, and on the Galaxy tab 2, so I can't figure out what the problem is. I even tried creating a dummy app with just a textView with a size of 40dip, and it still converted it to 60.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the answer to this question help you? Seems that he is having the same (or similar) problem.

[Android layout on emulator vs device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057410/android-layout-on-emulator-vs-device)

[Android, concerning the User Interface design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988473/android-concerning-the-user-interface-design)